# Conditional date formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a Google sheets table that is a being used as a wait list for a boutique hotel in San Francisco. Column F contains the requested arrival (Req.Arr) dates. I would like to use conditional formatting so that the individual rows display:

- Green if the Req.Arr date is > 60 days from TODAY
- Yellow if the Req.Arr date < 60 days from TODAY and > 45 days from TODAY
- Red if the Req.Arr date is < 45 days from TODAY

Comment: Can't open the link

Comment: What is your question? Did you try to add a conditional formatting with `TODAY()+60` /  `TODAY()+45`?

Answer (score 2):

**To format only the columns containing the dates** add a conditional formatting with "Format" -> "Conditional formatting".

- Apply to range `F:F` for complete column `F`.
- Format cells if `date is after` `exact date`.
- Set `value or formula` to `=TODAY()+60`.

Repeat for

- `date is before` `=TODAY()+61` and
- `date is before` `=TODAY()+46`.

Set the corresponding format in each condition. The order of your conditions is important. Alternatively you can set a custom formula for each condition.

**To format a whole row** you need custom rules.

- Add a rule with the range of your data (all columns and rows you want to format).
- Use `Custom formular is`.
- Set the formular to `=$F1 > TODAY() + 60` where `1` is the first row of your range.

This rule is applied to each field. Because of`$F` the column of the date is fixed. Add a rule with

- `=$F1 < TODAY() + 60` for yellow and
- `=$F1 < TODAY() + 45` for red

The order of this rules is important, too.

Here is a result of an example with 3 rules [image]

All three rules are for range `A2:L`. The rules are

- =$H2 > TODAY() + 60
- =AND($H2 < TODAY() + 45, $H2 > 0)
- =AND($H2 < TODAY() + 60, $H2 > 0)

The check for `$H2 > 0` is to avoid formatting empty rows.

Comment: Thomas, that worked great, but how can I highlight the entire row green, yellow or red rather than just the column?

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks Thomas for your help. Here is a link to the sheet:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GCSu-DIxzDCw5GTmHWtvleF-imueZoEQeTKFA2vQtk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSefbKKaFZMvhdCJHXvFKY72A1L-XmCMWK9NembBjrwKngDmow/formResponse

Comment: this the form I created for submissions to the wait list. by using the form, I can lock down the sheet and prevent people from accidentally deleting member requests.

Comment: I can't see the rules for conditional formatting. The first rule (green) for your example should be `=$H2 > TODAY() + 60` since `H` is the column with arrival dates and `2` is the first row of your data. The range for this rule is `A2:L`

Comment: Thanks again for your help yesterday.

Comment: I have set the conditional formatting that I need, but now there is another small problem. When I input the Google form linked to the Google sheet the resulting record on the sheet is placed on a row 2-4 rows below the last record on the sheet. Here is a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GCSu-DIxzDCw5GTmHWtvleF-imueZoEQeTKFA2vQtk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What I want is to have the sheet be updated with new records on the next row below the previous record, in other words, I do not want blank rows between records. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figured out the fix to my problem. I needed to highlight the entire sheet and then perform a Data > Sort Range > Column H > A-Z. Problem solved.